# Why does my nexus not boot?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I'm trying to get ubuntu on my nexus for more than a day now and i'm not able to get passt the initial image installation.
I managed to get to the boot screen and it turns wireless on, then off and on again.
After that there is no text but just a black screen. I've waited quite some time every time it happened but it never went further.

I'm using a mac and know that it's not even supported yet but i followed the manual installation and as it seems part of it worked. I tried to use a VM but i'm not able to mound my usb ports there so there is no use :/
After the normal install i tried it with multirom but experience the same problem...

Is there any hint on what i did wrong?

Here are my steps.

- Downloaded and extracted todays build (13.2.13)
- Erased boot and userdata with fastboot
- Flashed boot and userdata (even changed order)

I also tried wiping/formatting everything on the tablet first and setting permissions within TWRP
After messing with the permissions it even returned a mount error while booting. But no success.

*INFO:
Yesterdays build fixed it.